# How can I convert a field value to string for use in a custom category blog override?

Tags: php, category-blog

In Joomla (both 3x and 4x) I am trying to add a php 'if' query to a category blog override so that if the category title is 'X' then it does one thing, but if not, do something else. (I'm having trouble getting multiple overrides to work - but that's another issue - so I'm attempting to put two layouts into one override as a workaround.) Something like this:

`$catTitle = ($item->displayCategoryTitle);` in addition to the first 30-odd lines in the blog.php file

followed by the layout:

```
<?php if ($catTitle == 'myCategoryTitle') : ?>
<div class="outer-wrap">
    <?php foreach ($this->intro_items as $key => &$item) : ?>
        <div class="item-wrap">
            <?php
            $this->item = &$item;
            echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<? php endif; ?>
```

...followed by the other layout. Presumably I may need an `<?php else if ...`? or `<?php if ($catTitle != 'myCategoryTitle') : ?>`

At the moment, I'm - not surprisingly - just getting a blank screen.

Comment: The post title is about converting a field to a string but the body is about issues with If/then so I am not sure what you are having the issue with. Which field value are you wanting to convert, $catTitle? If you do a printr($catTitle) just before the first 'if' statement what does it look like?

Comment: Ok. I got the multiple overrides to work in the end, so this question is redundant. Sorry about the confusion over the 'string' nd 'if' statements.